# R : graph for text clustering

Tags: r, graph, text-analysis, data-science

I have dataframe which is as below,

```
    access  data    report  data$Week_No    data$Region
1    4       0        0       Week_3         Pacific
2    0       0        1       Week_3         Pacific
3    0       0        0       Week_3         Pacific
4    4       0        0       Week_3         Pacific
5    7       0        1       Week_3         Pacific
6    8       0        2       Week_3         Australia
7    0       0        2       Week_4         Singapore
8    2       0        1       Week_4         Kiribati
9    0       0        2       Week_1         Singapore
10   0       0        1       Week_1         Hong Kong
```

I want to plot this **x** & **y** axis as **data$Week_No** & **data$Region** where **access, data & report** are plotted as lines ,Can i convert numbers to decimal values and then plot it ?, i tried various way of achieving this , but result is not satisfactory, I have referred [this](http://connectmv.com/tutorials/r-tutorial/plots-with-multiple-series-colour-and-legends/#plot-the-first-series) , and have come up with this graph [image]

can i achieve better results with [such kind of graphical representation](https://sites.google.com/site/miningtwitter/questions/talking-about/given-topic) , Please guide me on this , thank you